# Update subarraylist in meteor collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have the game _id and player id both in session vars

```
  Games.insert({
      board : hex_board(7),
      players : [{id : 0, hexIds : []}, {id : 1, hexIds : []}],
  });
```

So far I'm stuck with:

```
  Games.update(Session.get("game"), {$addToSet : {players : ""}});
```

I do not know how to further refine which element in the players list it uses, but the criteria is in `Session.get("activePlayer")`.

**Almost working when the key is hardcoded to 0 or 1, I haven't made it dependent on the activePlayer var**

```
        Games.update(Session.get("game"), {
            $addToSet : {
                "players." + Session.get("activePlayer") + ".hexIds" : Session.get("selected_hex")
            }
        });
```

**Answer as method**

```
Meteor.methods({
  addHexIds : function (hexIds, player, game) {
    Games.update({_id:game, "players.id" : player}, {
            $addToSet : {
                "players.$.hexIds" : hexIds
            }
        });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this...

```
Games.update(
    { board : hex_board(7), "players.id": 0 },
    {
        "$addToSet": { "players.$.hexIds": "foo" }
    }
)
```

you can variablise as needed

Comment: This is it! You need to through it on the server side though and call it in the client since you can't update on the client with _id and other fields.

  Meteor.methods({
    addHexIds : function (hexIds, player, game) {
      Games.update({_id:game, "players.id" : player}, {
    $addToSet : {
     "players.$.hexIds" : hexIds
    }
   });
    }
  });